# Cannot access memory at adress 0x

Tags: c++

I have this project where I must create a society of objects (`creatures`) which is a separate object. I'm trying to do this by initializing an array of pointers to the object `creature` inside `creature_society`'s constructor (good and bad creatures are classes that inherit the class creature which is abstract)

```
creature_society::creature_society(int n, int L, int good_thrsh, int bad_thrsh)
{
  int a;
  creature **cArray = new creature * [n];
  gthrsh = good_thrsh;
  bthrsh = bad_thrsh;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    a = rand() % 2 ;
    if(a == 1)
      cArray[i] = new good_creature(L, i);
    else
      cArray[i] = new bad_creature(L, i);

    cout<< "\nhp is "<< cArray[i]->gethp() << "\n" << endl;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, creature society and the creatures are created but when I try to change a value of `cArray[i]` via a creature class function e.g.

```
void creature::bless()
{
  if(!is_a_zombie()) 
    hp++;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault and I get the message

```
cannot access memory at address 0x..
```

So my question is, why am I getting it? Is there something wrong with the cArray initialisation?

Comment: `creature **cArray=new creature * [n];` : it looks like you're declaring a local variable `cArray` instead of using a class member variable here.

Comment: `cArray` (being a local variable) is initialized and dynamically allocated but the pointer to allocated array is destroyed on `}` and it creates a memory leak. After this block if you have a `creature_society` field called `cArray` it is still uninitialized because you shadowed it with local variable.

Answer (score 1):

cArray is set during creature_society::creature_society

```
creature **cArray=new creature * [n];
```

outside of this method, you cannot access this variable. If you have another (global?) variable cArray, this will not be changed and probably stay at a value of 0, therefore pointing to address 0x.